# ASP.NET Core 2.2 How to call Custom UserValidator from Custom UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my CustomUserManager class

```
public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<User>
{
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    private readonly ManagementStudioDbContext dbContext;
    private IEnumerable<ICustomUserValidator<User>> userValidators;
    public CustomUserManager(ICustomUserStore<User> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
    IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<ICustomUserValidator<User>> userValidators,
    IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<User>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
    IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<User>> logger, ManagementStudioDbContext dbContext) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.userValidators = userValidators;
    }


    public override async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user, string Password)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        var result = await userValidators.
    }

}
```

I have managed to Create a custom UserValidator and a Custom UserStore class as well:

```
public class CustomUserStore<TUser> : UserStore<TUser> where TUser:IdentityUser<string>,new()
{
    private ManagementStudioDbContext dbContext;
    public CustomUserStore(ManagementStudioDbContext dbContext, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null) : base(dbContext, describer)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public virtual async Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
    {
        await base.CreateAsync(user);
    }
}

public class CustomUserValidator<TUser> : UserValidator<TUser>, ICustomUserValidator<TUser>
where TUser : User
{
    public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
    {
        if (manager == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(manager));
        }
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        }
        var errors = new List<IdentityError>();
        await ValidateUserName(manager, user, errors);
        if (manager.Options.User.RequireUniqueEmail)
        {
            //await ValidateEmail(manager, user, errors);
        }
        return errors.Count > 0 ? IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray()) : IdentityResult.Success;
    }

    private async Task ValidateUserName(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user, List<IdentityError> errors)
    {
        var userName = await manager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
        var securityStamp = await manager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
        {
            errors.Add(Describer.InvalidUserName(userName));
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(manager.Options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters) &&
            userName.Any(c => !manager.Options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters.Contains(c)))
        {
            errors.Add(Describer.InvalidUserName(userName));
        }
        else
        {
            var owner = manager.Users.Where(x => x.TenantId == user.TenantId && x.UserName.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (owner != null)
            {
                errors.Add(Describer.DuplicateUserName(userName));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However, I am unsure of how I can use these created classes within my UserManager class. I have tried calling userValidators but because it is an Ienumerable, I can't call my ValidateAsync function. I can't call my custom UserStore.CreateAsync as well because it's asking for a Cancellation Token.

How can I join these classes together to create a user?

EDIT: If possible, I don't see the need for a custom user store. However, I still need to use the userstore to createasync.